# CodeIgniter goes nuts when inserting file_get_contents into database

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm getting tons of lines of error code in the file core/security in many lines.

This ONLY happens because of this two lines of code:

```
$fileFinal = file_get_contents($fileTmp);
$projectFile['file'] = $fileFinal;
```

Although **I do know that is not the best practice to insert files into database**, that's not what's in question here.

This is my whole code:

```
$fileName = $file['name'];
$fileTmp  = $file['tmp_name']; 
$fileSize = $file['size']; 
$fileType = $file['type']; 

$fileFinal = file_get_contents($fileTmp);

if($fileFinal != null){

    $projectFile = array();

    $projectFile['file']        = $fileFinal;
    $projectFile['file_name']   = $fileName;
    $projectFile['file_type']   = $fileType;
    $projectFile['file_size']   = $fileSize;
    $projectFile['date']        = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $this->projectsModel->addFile($projectFile);
}
```

This works but with tons of errors. The files are actually inserted into database, but in my console I have dozens of lines of errors:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 8192
>
> Message:  preg_replace(): The /e modifier is
>   deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead
>
> Filename:
>   core/Security.php
>
> Line Number: 512
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 8192
>
> Message:  preg_replace(): The /e modifier is
>   deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead
>
> Filename:
>   core/Security.php
>
> Line Number: 513
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 8192
>
> Message:  preg_replace(): The /e modifier is
>   deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead
>
> Filename:
>   core/Security.php
>
> Line Number: 512
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 8192
>
> Message:  preg_replace(): The /e modifier is
>   deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead
>
> Filename:
>   core/Security.php
>
> Line Number: 513

And I can put here more errors. So I start debugging, line by line until I reach:

```
$projectFile['file'] = $fileFinal;
```

Changing this line to:

```
$projectFile['file'] = null;
```

Works perfectly and I do not receive any error.

The column in database that receives the field "file" is a `mediumblob` type.

I must repeat: Even with console errors my files are well inserted (somehow) in the database, however, my problem is that after inserting the file I send a `json_message` to `$.post`, and since it is full of errors I can not parse it correctly.

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter are you using?

Comment: The most recent 2.2.0. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems to be a bug, at least for me. I always use in my update and insert functions the `xss_clean()` function.

```
$this->security->xss_clean($data);
```

Which was the cause of the problem. By removing this, all the errors disappeared, which means that the `file_get_contents()` value are not welcome to this function.